# Faster way to open cached bitmaps in the default gallery

Tags: android, optimization, bitmap, android-intent, gallery

I have written a bit of code that when the listview is clicked, the image at that location is stored to external memory, then the file path string is sent with the intent to view the image in the default gallery. The only problem is that it takes a seriously long amount of time (I'm talking 10+ seconds on my thunderbolt).

What I haved tried:
1. Storing the bitmap on internal memory
2. Lowering the quality of the bitmap

Here is the code:

```
@Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
                    if(position>0){
                        Bitmap bmp =adapter.getBitmap(adapter.getData(position-1));
                        if(bmp!=null){
                            //String path = context.getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/view.png"; 
                            //File f = new File(context.getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath(),"MemeCache");
                            //if(!f.exists())
                            //    f.mkdirs();
                            String path = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/view.png"; 
                            Toast.makeText(context, "opening in gallery", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            File file = new File(path); 
                            FileOutputStream fos = null;
                            try {
                                fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                                bmp.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos ); 
                                fos.close(); 
                            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            Intent intent = new Intent();
                            intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(path)), "image/png");
                            //intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(f), "image/png");
                            activity.startActivity(intent);
                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(context, arg0.getItemAtPosition(position).toString() +"is HaAAACkSS!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: Where do the images come from in the first place? Is it possible to pass the Gallery the path to the original pictures, or to save them all to the SD card?

Comment: what part of the function you posted takes a long time to run? Please use the debugger to see which line it takes a long time to step-over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some things that might help:

1) add some timers or instrumentation to you code to see exactly where you're spending all the time: saving the bitmap to the sdcard, starting the intent, or something else entirely.

2) Once you've added timers and can measure the performance, you can see if shrinking the image or storing the image in a different place helps and if so how much.  On some devices, internal storage is on the sdcard itself.

3) depending on your program, you might want to consider pre-saving the files to the sdcard (possibly in the background) so that they are *probably* already saved by the time the user tries to view them in the gallery.